# Finding all palindromic numbers within a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

I need some help with below:

write a function (main) which will ask the user to enter a starting and ending number range (inclusive).  Count through the numbers using a while loop.  Add the number into the total only if it is a palindrome (call isNumberPalindrome).  Print the total after adding the numbers.'

What I have so far for this (main) function is...

```
def main():
start = int(input("Enter a number to start counting at:"))
end = int(input("Enter a number to end counting at:"))
while start <= end:
    print(start)
    start = start + 1
```

AND here is what I have for my (isNumberPalindrome) function.

```
def isNumberPalindrome(s):
if len(s) < 1:
        return True
else:
    if s[0] == s[-1]:
        return isNumberPalindrome(s[1:-1])
    else:
        return False
```

So far my (main) function asks for user input(starting and ending number) and counts them using a while loop.  I have no idea what to add to my code for (main) function next to achieve "Add the number into the total only if it is a palindrome (call isNumberPalindrome). Print the total after adding the numbers."

Thanks for the help.

So far with the code provided to me, this is what happens.

```
Enter a number to start counting at:1
Enter a number to end counting at:6
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/AWDADXC.py", line 38, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/AWDADXC.py", line 33, in main
if isNumberPalindrome(start):
File "C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/AWDADXC.py", line 18, in isNumberPalindrome
if len(s) < 1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: You should properly indent the contents of both functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple stab at this:

```
def isNumberPalindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]
filter(isNumberPalindrome, range(10,100))
```

Outputs:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
```

To sum them just pass the sequence to `sum()` like so:

```
sum(filter(isNumberPalindrome, range(10,100)))
```

Outputs:

```
495
```

And if you want to factor in user input you can do this:

```
sum(filter(isNumberPalindrome, range(int(raw_input('Enter a starting number:')), int(raw_input('enter a stopping number:')))))
```

Which will product the following output:

```
Enter a starting number:10
enter a stopping number:100
495
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over all integers from `start` to `end` inclusive:

```
for n in range(start, end + 1):
    print(n)
```

To get digits; you could use `str(n)`:

```
def is_palindrom(number):
    digits = str(number)
    return digits == digits[::-1]
```

where `s[::-1]` returns string `s` in reverse e.g., `"abc"[::-1] == "cba"`.

To find the sum of all palindromes in the range [start, end] inclusive:

```
total = sum(number for number in range(start, end + 1) if is_palindrom(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are calling `len` on an integer.
What you should do is call `len` on an iterable, e.g. `list` or `string`
(as in the solutions posted in the answers).

For example, and using your recursive implementation of `isNumberPalindrome`,

```
>>> isNumberPalindrome("123321")
True
>>> isNumberPalindrome("HelloolleH")
True
>>> isNumberPalindrome(str(123321))
True
>>> isNumberPalindrome([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])
True
```

Other than that, if it is not necessary to use your recursive implementation,
any of the other answers, should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
start = int(input("Enter a number to start counting at:"))
end = int(input("Enter a number to end counting at:"))
total = 0
while start <= end:
    print(start)
    if isNumberPalindrome(str(start)):
        total += start
    start = start + 1
print(total)
```

Comment: So using your code I am getting the start number to print in an endless loop instead of getting a total of only the palindromes.

Comment: I didn't remove the printing of the numbers because I thought you put that on purpose. However, I am not getting an infinite loop with this code. I'd recommend you check your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable which can store the sum of the palindromes. Than just call an if statement to check if the number is palindrome, if yes add the number into the total or else do nothing.

PS: You can use the code of Juampi provided in the another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is assuming that the parameter to `isNumberPalindrome` is a `str`, but you are passing an `int`

It's easy enough to check for a palindrome without going converting to a `str`. eg.

```
def isNumberPalindrome(n):  # n is an integer
    s = n
    t = 0
    while s:
        t = t*10 + s%10
        s /= 10
    return n == t
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - solution.

Specify the range with the input number

---

```
function findPalindromes(number) {

    let palindromeCount = 0;
    let leftSide = '';
    let rightSide = '';

    for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {

        let checkBox = [];
        let s = i.toString();

        for (let j = 0; j < s.length / 2; j++) {
            leftSide = s[j];
            rightSide = s[s.length - 1 - j];

            if (rightSide === leftSide) {
                checkBox.push('y');
            } else {
                checkBox.push('n');
            }
        }

        if (!checkBox.includes('n') && i > 10) {
            console.log(s);
            palindromeCount++;
        }
    }

    console.log(`TOTAL: ${palindromeCount} palindromes found`);
}

findPalindromes(1001);
```

[image: See the result]